# Has anyone else written about Terry Pratchett's other worlds?

Tags: novel, terry-pratchett, authors

Prior to writing about the Discworld, Terry Pratchett wrote about the worlds of *Strata*, and *Carpet People* and later the *Bromeliad Trilogy* (Truckers, Diggers, Wings).

These settings have not seen as much love and attention as the Discworld, but has anyone extended these universes into other novels or stories?

I'm thinking in a similar way that the Cthulhu mythos has grown over the years.

Comment: Well, there's [*Good Omens: The Nice and Accurate Prophecies of Agnes Nutter, Witch*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Good_Omens) his joint effort with Neil Gaiman.

Comment: @dmckee But that doesn't extend any of the titles above does it?

Comment: Nope. But it has the same kind of whimsy.

Comment: Jut a nitpick, the Johnny Maxwell trilogy and the Bromeliad trilogy were written after the Discworld novels became a success

Comment: @StuWilson I'll edit accordingly.

Comment: Strata is the same universe as Discworld isn't it?

Comment: @Nick I don't think so...

Comment: @Pureferret Its a book about people who make planets, who find a flat disc-world with magic carpets and suchlike on....

Comment: I realise that, but that's no proof they are coterminous.

Comment: One reason the Cthulhu mythos has grown so much is that Lovecraft permitted -- nay, actively encouraged -- other writers to have fun in his playground. His estate follows the same policy. Pratchett hasn't done anything like that.

Comment: @Nick - It's not the same world. The world of Stata is a technodisk, with an internal (mechanical) structure. The discworld is a natural structure comprised of rock and metal, resting atop four elephants.

Comment: @Richard as far as we know...How far down have we gone in either?

Comment: @Pureferret - Well, the dwarves in the Discworld series have mined well below the depth of the techno-layer in Strata.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> [...] has anyone extended these universes into other novels or stories?

No, I don't think so.

Of course, there *might* be some fanfic out there somewhere, but I seriously doubt it. Most of the fandom concentrates on what's by far the largest part of Pratchett's output: Discworld.

Comment: Not quite true. I'm told there's plenty of Aziraphale/Crowly slash out there for the reading if you're into that kind of thing.

Comment: @TRiG: "Of course, there might be some fanfic out there somewhere..." And then [he said](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/14650/has-anyone-else-written-about-terry-pratchetts-other-worlds/24962#comment27015_14650): _"But that doesn't extend any of the titles above does it?"_